# How to create a sub-set array

Tags: php, arrays, subset

Given an array for example:

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
```

how can I create an array containing all the possible sub sets:

```
[1, 2, 3, [1,2], [1,3],[2,3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think thats a great question - Finding subsets of a set has several approaches
I prefer using the binary approach:

There are `n^2` susets for a given set of `n`. You can count in binary from 0 to 2^n and interpret the binary number as the corresponding subset. Note that this approach requires a binary number with a sufficient amount of digits to represent the whole set so we need to pad the binary representation.

**More Reading**: [binary-subsets](http://www.keithschwarz.com/binary-subsets/)

**My implementation**:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3);
$res = subsets($arr);

function subsets($arr,$sort = true,$include_empty = false,$include_full = false) {
   $length = count($arr);
   $res = array();
   if (!$length && $include_full) return $res;
   for ($i = 0; $i<pow(2, $length); $i++) {
       $set = array();
       $bin = str_split(str_pad(decbin($i), $length, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
       $binLen = count($bin);
       for ($j = 0; $j < $binLen; $j++)
           if ($bin[$j] === "1") $set[] = $arr[$j];
       $res[] = $set;
    }
    foreach($res as $k => $val)
       if (!count($val) && !$include_empty) unset($res[$k]);
       elseif (count($val) === $length && !$include_full) unset($res[$k]);
    function cmp($a, $b){ return (count($a) - count($b)); }
    if ($sort) usort($res, 'cmp');
    return $res;
}

//Output Results:
foreach ($res as $key => $data) {
   echo $key." -> [".(implode(',',$data))."]\r";
}
/*
0 -> [1]
1 -> [3]
2 -> [2]
3 -> [1,2]
4 -> [2,3]
5 -> [1,3]
*/
```

As you can see the function handles an input array and you can choose whether to include an empty set and the full set in the result or not.

You should know that the number of iterations is increasing dramatically:

Without removing empty set or full set:

```
n*(2^n)
```

with removing:

```
(2^n) + n*(2^n)
```

with removing & sorting (worst case):

```
(2^n) + n*(2^n) + n^2
```

Let say we have an input array with 9 values:

```
(2^9)*9 = 4608;

(2^9) + 9*(2^9) = 5120;

(2^9) + 9*(2^9) + 9^2 = 5201;
```

That's the fastest way I know.

**Note**:
The function expects a unique array - you can make sure your array is unique:

```
$arr = array_unique ($arr);
```